# Linear velocity x and y are greater than zero, but still no movement

Tags: javascript, box2dweb

So I have something going on that's confusing me, involving a body not moving. I used the `SetLinearVelocity()` member function on a body, like so:

```
dude.body.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0.1, 0.1));
```

I then place a `console.log()` right before calling the `Step` function:

```
console.log(dude.body.GetPosition().x);
console.log(dude.body.m_linearVelocity);
world.Step(1/60, 10, 10);
console.log(dude.body.GetPosition().x);
```

This is in my game animation loop, so the `console.log` gets called over and over. It says `m_linearVelocity` is a `b2Vec2` with an `x` value of 0.1 and a `y` value of 0.1.

So right before the `Step` function call, the the x and y values of `m_linearVelocity` are greater than zero, but there is never any change in `dude.body.GetPosition().x` from the beginning of the above snippet to the end.

I don't know where to start in tracking down the problem, because this makes no sense to me. Does anyone know why this might happen?

edit: I should add, it worked when there was gravity, but in zero gravity, it won't move, even though the linear velocity is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. However, instead of the `WakeUp()` function in the example, I need to use `SetAwake(true)`:

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3181